# how to get socket id of connected users

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I have a unique token for all login users and now i want when the third party server connect with my socket after find the token of token array if that token is available i have to get text message through hitting the web service after that i have to send data using socket emit function to that user which token is match but i need that user socket id also. how can i find the socket id of each login user? 
And emit the message to that socket id using token.

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
var session = require('client-sessions');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var request = require('request');
var utils = require('utility');
app.use(bodyParser.text());
 var token_array = new Array();
require('array.prototype.find');


app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'usersession',
  secret: '0GB2ZbiKBtz2flRPvlJZ9EtczCewBxXK',
 duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // how long the session will stay valid in ms
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5
}));
```

........................................................................

```
app.post("/login", urlEncodedParser, function(req, response)
           {

                var body = req.body;
                console.log(req.body);
                var userData={
                    "deviceToken" : "AbcDE1234567",
                    "password" : body.pwd,
                    "username" : body.username
                };
                var digest = utils.hmac("sha1", "A12AA418-1F28-4464-8B67-29CBD02BC45C-F048B14F-F3E3-4F97-A522-F2275A364A0E", JSON.stringify(userData));
                var postData = {
                    "deviceToken" : "AbcDE1234567",
                    "password"    : body.pwd,
                    "username"    : body.username,
                    "digest"      : digest
                };

                var sPostData = utils.base64encode(utils.base64encode(JSON.stringify(postData)));
                request({
                    url: "http://201.196.6.218:8080/BACKSTAFF/service/authenticate/",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: sPostData
                },
                function(err,result,body){
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));

                    var body = JSON.parse(body);
                //  console.log(typeof body);
                    //console.log(body.token);
                    req.usersession.token = body.token;
                    token_array.push(body.token);
                    req.usersession.alltoken= token_array
                    //console.log(token_array);
                    response.redirect(301, '/contacts');
                }); 


            });



io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('push', function(msg_id,token){
      console.log(token_array);
 // console.log(token_array.find('244d6575-fc60-4815-a331-274a24d65a95'));

   Array.prototype.contains = function(elem)
{
for (var i in this)
{
if (this[i] == elem) return true;
}
return false;
}

if (token_array.contains('66a1fd91-86d6-4884-b483-167ca5ff005f'))
{

    var msgData={

                    "messageID" : msg_id,
                     "token" : token

                };
    var digest = utils.hmac("sha1", "A12AA418-1F28-4464-8B67-29CBD02BC45C-F048B14F-F3E3-4F97-A522-F2275A364A0E", JSON.stringify(userData));

    var msgPostData = {

        "token" : token,
        "messageID" : msg_id,
        "digest" :digest

    };
        var msgencodeData = utils.base64encode(utils.base64encode(JSON.stringify(postData)));
                request({
                    url: "http://201.196.6.218:8080/BACKSTAFF/service/getTextMessage/",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: msgencodeData
                },
                function(err,result,body){
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));

                    var body = JSON.parse(body);
                    var message = body.message;
                    socket.emit('push', message);
                }); 






}
else
{
console.log('no');  
}

   // io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

});
```

..............................................................

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of sockets (by token for example) you should keep them in an object. So when a client connects you save the socket in the object like below:

```
var clientObj = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  clientObj[token] = socket;
  ...
}
```

Then you can emit to the socket like this:

```
io.to(clientObj[token]).emit('something', 'some message');
```